# Handle French Char in Response while getting using REST Template Spring Boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have below piece of code:

```
**RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
HttpEntity<?> requestObject = new HttpEntity<>(request,headers);
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, requestObject, String.class);**
```

Now we are getting french char like 'Numéro'. while getting response in result variable it became 'Numï¿½ro' .. I need same as we have in response ('Numéro').

Answer (score 1):

Try setting content type in headers.

```
headers.setAccept(new ArrayList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

Comment: what is newArrayList here ? I tried it below:   headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));  But it didnt work